# Laravel count topics

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Currently I'm sending this back in my api:

```
return Forum::with('topics')
          ->paginate($pagination);
```

So a forum has many topics. How can I count all topics and send them back with this json response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**According to Laravels' documentation:**

> The Laravel paginator result classes implement the
>   Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Jsonable  Interface contract and expose
>   the toJson method, so it's very easy to convert your pagination
>   results to JSON.  You may also convert a paginator instance to JSON by
>   simply returning it from a route or controller action:

```
Route::get('users', function () {
    return App\User::paginate();
});
```

> The JSON from the paginator will include meta information such as
>   total, current_page, last_page, and more. The actual result objects
>   will be available via the data key in the JSON array. Here is an
>   example of the JSON created by returning a paginator instance from a
>   route:

```
{
   "total": 50,
   "per_page": 15,
   "current_page": 1,
   "last_page": 4,
   "next_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=2",
   "prev_page_url": null,
   "from": 1,
   "to": 15,
   "data":[
        {
            // Result Object
        },
        {
            // Result Object
        }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need to get the list of all forums with related topics and pagination and also the total count of topics, you can return an array with needed data structure

```
return [
    'forums' => Forum::with('topics')->paginate($onPage)->toArray(),
    'topics_total_count' => Topic::count()
];
```

Note the `->toArray()` usage. It's needed because of `paginate()` method itself returns `Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator` instance.
It won't be serialized to json automatically if you don't return the pagination object directly from controller.